# Select and update specific div from many other div using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have a social network site where 100s of posts are being displayed in a loop, it is similar to facebook timeline. 
What I am trying to do is update a specific part of a post asynchronously, but i can't select the targetted div because there are 100s of other div that containing the same class.

I have tried:

```
    $(this).find('.response-content).html(data);
```

But it did not work. When I try:

```
    $('.response-content).html(data);
```

It works, but all the posts are being updated instead of the desired one. I have tried to give the unique class name for all the posts but that also seemed difficult to get the post id in jquery selector.
Please help.
 [In the screenshot you will see I have evaluation heart below each post, all I want is to update the icon based on the evaluation I made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeYsK.jpg)

Your help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's the jquery:

```
        $('#evaluatePost button').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var evaluationScore = $(this).val();
    var formData = new FormData(this.form);
    formData.append("ratedAs", evaluationScore);
    $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/koolw/public/evaluate',
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
              $(this).find('.response-content').html(data);

            },
            error: function(data){
               console.log(data);
            }
        });

});
```

Note: I have at least 50 '.response-content' class in the page. So, how can I select the specific one?

Comment: Your question is fine, but show us your code, specifically how're your preparing your DOM. Without it, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

## What about using .eq() function?

Here are the simple example.

> ```
>   <!DOCTYPE html>
>     <html>
>     <head>
>       <title>Testing</title>
>       <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
>       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js"></script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>       <div class="content"> 
>           <p>Hello</p>
>       </div>
>       <div class="content"> 
>           <p>Hello</p>
>       </div>
>       <div class="content"> 
>           <p>Hello</p>
>       </div>
>       <script>
>          $(document).ready(function() {
>               $(this).find('.content').eq(0).css( "background-color", "red" );
>           });
>       </script>
>     </body>
>     </html>
> ```

Reference: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/